# Search in MVC 4 and rendering in Same view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

i'm trying the search in the index of a controller, to retrieve the search result in the same view (index),
for that this is the action:

```
public ActionResult Index(string SeatchParam)
{
 var Employees = db.Employees.Include(e => e.Location).Include(e =>          e.Department).Where(e => e.FirstName.Contains(SeatchParam)|| e.FatherName.Contains(SeatchParam) || e.LastName.Contains(SeatchParam) || e.Location.LocationName.Contains(SeatchParam) || e.Department.DepartmentName.Contains(SeatchParam)).Take(10);
        return View(Employees.ToList());
    }
```

and the view is like:

```
@model IEnumerable<OG.Models.Employee>

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Search Employees</h2>

<form action="Employee/Index"  method="get">
<input type="text" name="SearchParam" />
<input type="submit" value="Search" />


<p>
@Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>


<table border="10">
<tr>

   <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.EmployeeId)
    </th>

    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FullName)
    </th>

    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Department.DepartmentName)
    </th>

     <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Location.LocationName)
    </th>

    <th></th>
</tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EmployeeId)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FullName)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Department.DepartmentName)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Location.LocationName)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.EmployeeId  }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.EmployeeId }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.EmployeeId })
    </td>
</tr>
}

</table>
</form>
```

when i search, i found no result, could i do that without AJAX or Json???
Thanks,

Comment: You have pasted your Controller code twice but not your view code. Can you post also your view? Are you sure that there is data in the db which matches the search param? Have you debugger your action do you get the right `SeatchParam`?

Comment: Could it be because you spelled the action parameter differently from the input? `string SeatchParam` > `name="SearchParam"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You pass `SeatchParam` into your controller while your input is called `SearchParam`

so change

```
public ActionResult Index(string SearchParam)
```